# Rows into columns in a multi-index Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a DataFrame with a multi-index, one of dates and the other numbered from 0 to 1267 as the image shows.

How do I have the index 0-1267 as columns instead of rows and have the dates as the only row index?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select some column and then use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) by first level:

```
df1 = df['CUMULATIVE FRACTION'].unstack(0)
```

Or if need `MultiIndex` in columns use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df2 = df.unstack(0)
```

Comment: an error shows up: "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". Is it because the rows have different dates?

Comment: @K.lid problem is duplicates, try

Comment: try what, sorry?

Comment: @K.lid try `df1 = df. groupby(df. index). mean()['CUMULATIVE FRACTION'].unstack(0)` or  `df1 = df. groupby(df. index).sum()['CUMULATIVE FRACTION'].unstack(0)` for aggregate values.